# mapstruct: mapping field names to properties

Tags: java, mapstruct

Source classes:

```
class ReportSettings {
    private HeaderSettings headerSettings;
    private FooterSettings footerSettings;

    // getters and setters omitted
}

class HeaderSettings {
    private boolean showLogo;

    // getters and setters omitted
}

class FooterSettings {
    private boolean showPageNumber;

    // getters and setters omitted
}
```

Target class:

```
class Parameters {
    private String group;
    private String name;
    private String value;

    // getters and setters omitted
}
```

Is it possible using MapStruct to convert a `ReportSettings` object to  `List<Parameters>` object like below where the field names from the `ReportSettings` class are mapped to the `Parameter` class's `group` field:

```
group           | name           | value
----------------------------------------
headerSettings  | showLogo       | false
footerSettings  | showPageNumber | true
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there is no such functionality in place that will dynamically create a list based on field names.

The only idea that comes into my mind would be a really static solution, but I guess that you have a dynamic list of fields and can't do it in this way.

```java
@Mapper
public abstract class ReportSettingsMapper {

  @Mappings({
    @Mapping(target = "group", constant = "headerSettings"),
    @Mapping(target = "name", constant = "showLogo"),
    @Mapping(target = "value", source = "headerSettings.showLogo")
  })
  protected abstract Parameters mapHeaderSettings(ReportSettings settings);

  @Mappings({
    @Mapping(target = "group", constant = "footerSettings"),
    @Mapping(target = "name", constant = "showPageNumber"),
    @Mapping(target = "value", source = "footerSettings.showPageNumber")
  })
  protected abstract Parameters mapFooterSettings(ReportSettings settings);

  public List<Parameters> mapReportSettings(ReportSettings settings) {
    List<Parameters> parameters = new ArrayList<>();
    parameters.add( mapHeaderSettings(settings) );
    parameters.add( mapFooterSettings(settings) );

    return parameters;
  }
}
```

(untested code; if you use Java >= 8 you can use an interface with default methods + remove the `@Mappings` container annotation)